# Error when trying to post a discussion 'comment' to a work item using the Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-rest-api

I am trying to post a discussion comment to a work item using the  REST API **version=5.1-preview.3**.

**Summary**

Type: POST and C# HttpClient

However no matter how i try to work with it, i always get the response:

```
StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'
```

The inner response is something like this:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: d634683c-0b2e-4bfb-9a66-ee99f32404c6.","typeName":"System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException, System.Web.Http","typeKey":"HttpResponseException..
```

I send the  data/comment in the following JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Test Comment"
  }
]
```

As mentioned in the docs :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples

**Request**

I am trying to hit the API:

POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/workItems/299/comments?api-version=5.1-preview.3

using the below sample code:

```
public class Comment
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

```
var comment = new Comment()
{
    Text = "Test Comment"
};

var comments = new List<Comment>();
comments.Add(comment);

var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comments);

var postValue = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");


using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", _token))));

      using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _apiUrl) { Content = postValue })
      {
          var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
      }
}
```

I believe the above snippet should be able to add a comment to the work item. However no matter how i try to work with it, i always get the response:

**Response**

```
StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type'
```

The inner response is something like this:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: d634683c-0b2e-4bfb-9a66-ee99f32404c6.","typeName":"System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException, System.Web.Http","typeKey":"HttpResponseException..
```

Could you please help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think you need the square `[ ]` brackets in the JSON body. `{
"text": "Test Comment" }`

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply, however, this does not seem to be working. I get the same response (415)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the response.

The changes suggested by @Michael along with the following change did the trick.

```
var postValue = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Updated the content type "application/json-patch+json" to "application/json".

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/606944/cannot-add-comments-to-a-work-item-with-api-versio.html) is a similar thread discussing this issue on Developer Community.

I agree with Michael's comment above and it works without the enclosing `[]`, which does not align with the example provided in the official REST API documentation.

I would recommend you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues) and get this corrected in the docs as well. You might also open an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to get immediate assistance from the Azure DevOps Team.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!